# Spivak chapter 5, 3.3. Limit help

Tags: calculus, limits

Question: Determine the limit $l$ for the given $a$  and prove that it is the limit by showing hot to find a $\delta$ such that $|f(x) - l|< \epsilon$   for all $x$ satisfying $0< |x-a| < \delta$

$f(x) = \frac {100}{x}$ , $a=1$

Answer: $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) = 100 $

$|\frac {100}{x} -100| < \epsilon$

$|100| \frac {|1-x|}{|x|} < \epsilon$

Can I just say,

$\delta = \frac{|x| \epsilon}{100}$  ?

Can I get a hint as to how to move beyond this?

Comment: Not quite, your expression for $\delta$ can't have $x$ appearing in it.

Comment: @angryavian why not?. Limit definition in the book only cares about the existence of $\delta$ not how its defined. Is is because $x$ can be 0 ?

Comment: There are many values of $x$, but you need to find one constant value of $\delta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You end up with the inequality
$$
\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}<\frac{\varepsilon}{100}. \tag{1}
$$

In such cases you first need to make a rough restriction of $x$, so that $\frac{1}{|x|}$ stays bounded, i.e. $\frac{1}{2}<x<\frac{3}{2}$, which is obtained for $\delta=1/2$.

Having made this restriction $(1)$ reduces to satisfaction of
$$
\frac{|x-1|}{|x|}<\frac{|x-1|}{\frac{1}{2}}<\frac{\varepsilon}{100},
$$
or
$$
|x-1|<\frac{\varepsilon}{200}.
$$
Now check that $\delta=\varepsilon/200$ does your job.

Comment: @yiorogos thank you. Why does $\frac {1}{|x|}$ need to stay bounded? I guess I am not sure what that means.

Comment: The important this is to end up bounding $|x-1|$. All the other factors should be taken care by rough bounds. So in order to get rid of $\frac{1}{|x|}$ you need to make a rough restriction of $|x-1|$: a first rough estimate of $\delta$ which allows you to restrict your attention on $|x-1|$.

Answer (score 1):

This may not really be an answer but it is too complicated for a comment - sorry.

The definition of
$$\lim_{x\to a}f(x)=l$$
is
$$\displaylines{
  \hbox{for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that}\cr
  \hbox{for all $x$, if $0<|x-a|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.}\cr}$$
Since a particular choice of $\delta$ must work **for all** $x$, the value of $\delta$ cannot depend on $x$.

To put it another way, if you want to prove a limit statement (or at least, to do so by the most straightforward manner) you will need something like the following template.

**Proof**.
Let $\varepsilon>0$.
Choose $\delta=\cdots\,$.
Suppose that $0<|x-a|<\delta$.
Then. . .
. . . and so $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

In the line where you choose $\delta$, you cannot rely on $x$ since it has not yet been specified.